# Split and switch to bottom window when opening vim

Tags: split

When I open a file of a given filetype I want it to split into two windows with the cursor in the bottom window. I can get this to work when opening the file from an existing vim session. But when I open the file in vim from the command line the cursor always starts in the top window.

I made a simple file, split.vim, to demonstrate what is happening (in my real case I use `autocmd FileType` but this simpler case also reproduces it:

> `botright split`

If I open vim with `vim -u split.vim` it splits as expected, but the cursor is in the top window.

However, if vim is already running and I do `:source split.vim` it does the same split, but the cursor is in the bottom window.

How can I get vim to split with the cursor in the bottom window, even when first opening vim?

I've also tried adding `wincmd j` after making the split, but the result is the same.

Again, my actual use case uses `autocmd` for a given filetype, but the above is easier to test with no vimrc. The `autocmd` case has the same results. If I open a file when opening vim the cursor remains in the top window. But if I open a file of the specified filetype the cursor jumps to the bottom window.

Comment: what about `vim -c "botright split"`?

Comment: if I add to my vimrc `au VimEnter * botright split` then when I start vim I get 2 split wins and cursor is on the bottom one.

Comment: I'm actually doing this for a specific filetype, whether opened from the command line, or in an existing session (edited to call that out earlier). Though maybe I could set a flag that ```au VimEnter``` checks before doing the split...

Comment: Most autocommands allow you to specify the (extension of the) file type to which they apply so ... `autocmd VimEnter *.py botright split` ... for python files, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the commenters I came up with the following solution.

```
au FileType tsv botright split   " split in any case a .tsv is opened
au VimEnter *.tsv wincmd j       " workaround to move window if opened from cli
```